# Access php error logs in Docker

Tags: php, docker

How can I access the php error logs for my container?

For some reason I'm really struggling to find out how to do this after a long time of searching various articles.

I'm using a simple php7 apache container which looks like:
FROM php:7-apache

```
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
        libpng12-dev \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        curl \
        libcurl4-openssl-dev \
        libxpm-dev \
        libvpx-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    --with-freetype-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    --with-xpm-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    --with-vpx-dir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
        pdo \
        pdo_mysql \
        gd \
        curl \
    && a2enmod rewrite \
    && service apache2 restart
```

Ideally I just need to view the contents of the error log or get a new custom log set locally on my machine so I easily see potential issues with my site build.

Any pointers appreciated. I found the docker documentation very confusing on the topic of logs...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It exists the following docker command:

```
docker logs -f --details containerName
```

that will show you the mysql and php errors log files

for more check the documentation: [docker logs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/)

Comment: the (--details) is in paranthese, because it is optional and should be `--details` if you want to add it

Comment: I know that, but a user new to Docker may not.

Comment: yes, sorry about that I just copied from a cheatsheet of mine

Comment: When I add --details to check php-fpm logs `docker logs --details docker_php-fpm_1` I do not get any more details. All stays the same. Just basic:
 `172.25.0.8 -  30/Jan/2019:11:06:52 +0000 "POST /index.php" 500
  172.25.0.8 -  30/Jan/2019:11:06:59 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
 172.25.0.8 -  31/Jan/2019:00:49:46 +0000 "GET /index.php" 404
 172.25.0.8 -  31/Jan/2019:00:50:28 +0000 "GET /info.php" 200`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55207245/apache-php-error-log-location-in-docker

Comment: It'd be nice if the details option was available for docker compose as well. That said, I don't see, currently, any more information when adding that option, than I do without it.

Answer (score 7):

By default the container doesn't seem to log PHP errors to STDOUT or STDERR. I found that when using the `php.ini-development` config file (see 'Configuration' in [this article](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/)) it logs a lot more useful information.

To view the logs for a container, the most basic way is to do `docker ps`, find the container hash, and then do `docker logs container_hash`.

*Note: This config file will contain some unsafe values for production. You should really create your own config file with the desired logging settings.*

Comment: Thank you for this! Finally getting my PHP logs since using `mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-development" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"` when building the Docker Container 

Answer (score 2):

All PHP output will be in the container, so you can use all the docker goodies to access the logs...

My favorite is `attach` as it allows you to follow the logs in real time. ( `docker attach containerName` )

There's also `logs` to see the past logs. `docker logs containerName`  will print out all the output from the container. You might prefer adding the `--tail=N` flag where N is the number of lines to get.

Comment: PHP output is not always added to the container output.