# Apache / PHP error_log location in Docker

Tags: php, apache, docker, logging, error-logging

My PHP script has an error. For example, this shows this on the screen:

> Warning: require(/var/www/foo.php): failed to open stream:

Where can I find this in the logs?

I tried `docker logs containerName`, but it only shows access logs. E.g.,

`192.168.2.1 - - [17/Mar/2019:10:00:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 505 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)...`

It doesn't show the PHP error above.

Going in the Apache logs folder inside the container via `docker exec` shows the following:

```
ls -hltra /var/log/apache2

total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 www-data www-data 11 Feb  6 04:42 other_vhosts_access.log -> /dev/stdout
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 www-data www-data 11 Feb  6 04:42 error.log -> /dev/stderr
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 www-data www-data 11 Feb  6 04:42 access.log -> /dev/stdout
```

I'm not even sure if this is where the PHP logs are at, but I can't view them.

Where can I find the Apache/PHP error logs in Docker?

Comment: Related, for locating the PHP error log: *[Where does PHP store the error log? (PHP 5, Apache, FastCGI, and cPanel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/)* (despite the over-specific title).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ensure that you have the following inside `php.ini` in order to be able to see the errors using `docker logs -f containerName` as in general, sending the logs to `/dev/stdout` and `/dev/stderr` makes you able to receive it through `docker logs`:

```
log_errors = On
error_log = /dev/stderr
```

Comment: this gets me something like this `[07/Oct/2021:21:55:51 +0000] "POST /sales-channel-api/v3/backinstock/subscribe HTTP/1.1" 500 831` ... pretty useless unless I can see what actually caused the 500

Comment: @DanielFanica I came across this issue again and encoutered something similar to that "pretty useless" logs. In my case my `vhost.conf` is causing issues because of a custom log directive that has no Docker volume. Basically, just make sure logs in `vhost.conf` has no issues first so PHP can properly log in `stderr`.

Answer (score 4):

To only see PHP logs, try:

```
docker logs -f [containerName] >/dev/null
```

To see all logs, try:

```
docker logs -f [containerName]
```

Comment: What is the point of leaving out the verbs?

Answer (score 0):

Running Apache2 in the docker-compose.yml as foreground process did make the logging work.

```yaml
entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "apachectl -D FOREGROUND"]
```

This does not require to enable logging and redirecting in the php.ini file using the [fpm8-3:apache](https://hub.docker.com/layers/library/php/8.3-apache/images/sha256-4f45de8893b4c6a365c22b4d15e0c9ac42d3a41e90f352b5b7fbf807ef7dc850?context=explore) docker image.

Comment: Is there a way to  make the logging working for an running container?

Comment: @Freude I do not think so, because only running as foreground process and not as service enables the apache2 logging into logfiles - at least with that image.